# How to let child access the parent data( an array of object), while having the child ability to update them

Tags: reactjs

I have two components in my project.

One is App.jsx

One is Child.jsx

In App, there is a state holding array of child state objects. All create, manage, and update of the child state is through a set function from parent.

So, Child componment doesnt have its own state. For some reason, it is my intention not to have child own state, because it matters.

However, at some points, I found it that passing data into child would be hard to manage.

Question:

So, is there a way that let the **child to access the data from parent by themselves** not by passing down, while **having them be able to update** the state like my code.

People say useContext may work, but I dont quite see how.

A example to illustrate would be prefect for the improvement.

```
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.18.12/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">


const {StrictMode, useState} = React;


function getInitialChildState () {
  return {
    hidden: false,
    id: window.crypto.randomUUID(),
    text: '',
  };
}


function Child ({text, setText}) {
  return (
    <div className="vertical">
      <div>{text ? text : 'Empty '}</div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={ev => setText(ev.target.value)}
        value={text}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


function ChildListItem ({state, updateState}) {
  const toggleHidden = () => updateState({hidden: !state.hidden});
  const setText = (text) => updateState({text});
  return (
    <li className="vertical">
      <button onClick={toggleHidden}>{
        state.hidden
          ? 'Show'
          : 'Hide'
      } child</button>
      {
        state.hidden
          ? null
          : <Child text={state.text} setText={setText} />
      }
    </li>
  );
}

function App () {
  // Array of child states:
  const [childStates, setChildStates] = useState([]);

  // Append a new child state to the end of the states array:
  const addChild = () => setChildStates(arr => [...arr, getInitialChildState()]);

  // Returns a function that allows updating a specific child's state
  // based on its ID:
  const createChildStateUpdateFn = (id) => (updatedChildState) => {
    setChildStates(states => {
      const childIndex = states.findIndex(state => state.id === id);
      // If the ID was not found, just return the original state (don't update):
      if (childIndex === -1) return states;
      // Create a shallow copy of the states array:
      const statesCopy = [...states];
      // Get an object reference to the targeted child state:
      const childState = statesCopy[childIndex];
      // Replace the child state object in the array copy with a NEW object
      // that includes all of the original properties and merges in all of the
      // updated properties:
      statesCopy[childIndex] = {...childState, ...updatedChildState};
      // Return the array copy of the child states:
      return statesCopy;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Parent</h1>
      <button onClick={addChild}>Add child</button>
      <ul className="vertical">
        {
          childStates.map(state => (
            <ChildListItem
              // Every list item needs a unique key:
              key={state.id}
              state={state}
              // Create a function for updating a child's state
              // without needing its ID:
              updateState={createChildStateUpdateFn(state.id)}
            />
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

reactRoot.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

</script>
```

Comment: The code works fine. Do you have any particular problem? You can use [easy peasy](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/easy-peasy) to simplify a bit.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way that let the child to access the data from parent by themselves not by passing down, while having them be able to update the state like my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually context in react is used for a global things like themes and authentication. But you can use it for actions too.

```
const AppContext = createContext();
```

In `App`:

```
const getChildState = (id) => ...
const updatedChildState = (id, updatedChildState) =>
```

```
<AppContext.Provider value={{ getChildState, updatedChildState }}>...
```

In `ChildListItem`:

```
const { getChildState, updatedChildState } = useContext(AppContext);
const state = getChildState(id);
const setText = (text) => updatedChildState(id, { text });
```

You need to pass down the `id` anyway so `ChildListItem` know what to get and what to update:

```
<ChildListItem key={state.id} id={state.id} />
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-wave-xvkshb?file=/src/App.js:582-754)

**Update**

Regarding your question about the theme and authentication examples let's first cite the documentation:

> In a typical React application, data is passed top-down (parent to
> child) via props, but such usage can be cumbersome for certain types
> of props (e.g. locale preference, UI theme) that are required by many
> components within an application. Context provides a way to share
> values like these between components without having to explicitly pass
> a prop through every level of the tree.

Examples:

- Material UI uses `ThemeProvider` to pass down `theme` object. Thus all components can access the palette, typography etc.
- Many apps uses context to pass down information about a currently logged in user. So all components can render accordingly.

Comment: It is so good! thanks a lot

Comment: apart from it, May I ask , when you say use context is not good for this example, May I ask for some easy examples on what you meant by themes and authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You could try jotai atoms

App.jsx

```
import { atom, useAtom } from 'jotai'

export const itemAtom = atom('')

export const App = () => {
  const [item] = useAtom(itemAtom)
  <p>{item}</p>
  ...
}
```

Child.jsx

```
export const Child = () => {
  const [, setItem] = useAtom(itemAtom)
  <input onChange={(e) => setItem(e.value)} />
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, The code seems not quite relevant to my examples data? I dont quite understand it. May you provide some extra explanation on the code?

Comment: You can look up jotai. useAtom is kind of like useState that can be passed around to all of your components